# Jmeter Max value decresae over time

Tags: jmeter

I'm using jmeter 5 to launch a simple load test. now i want to understand console output. But i have the difficulty with **max value**.

I was expected that **max** is a Maximum elapsed time of all the requests. But during the load test, his value decrease and increase.

Load test parameter:

- loops: 1000
- concurent threads: 5
- rand-up: 1s

The image below show my console output. And you can see the max value decrease and increase. I don't know why.

[image]

please someone can explain me ? I have a some problems to understand variations of other values.

Comment: Detail your set up, please. What exactly you send to Influx, which way; where do you observe results, if it is Grafana - how your queries are built, stuff like that.

Comment: @YuriG the post has edited

Comment: Where did the Influx thing go, I wonder? Although, whatever. The answer is pretty obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.

There, on that picture, you've got two types of reporting records:

1) Ones with "summary =" are overall, for the whole test duration. 
As you can see, there Max values are gradually, but slowly, changes towards increase (Mins do the opposite, expectedly).
Which is expected. I shouldn't go for a why-s here, right?

2) Ones with "summary + " are delta.
That's what was added for a certain time period (30 sec here), and all the values you observe there are calculated for that time span ONLY.
Again, obviously - they are different, and independent of each other.

So, concluding: nothing actually "jumps" up there, everything works as expected, you'd just misinterpret it.

Hope that soothes your concerns.

P.S. You'd cleared any mentions of InfluxDB & Grafana out of the questions, but I have to add that it works similar way for that bundle: these values depends on a timeframe & grouping by time (smaller time chunks) within this timeframe.